# Xcode 8 Beta 5 Strange Error dyld symbol not found

Tags: swift, tvos, xcode8-beta4

I've updated to the new beta and I for some reason cannot get my framework to run on tvOS anymore with this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TMps23ExpressibleByNilLiteral
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F88A3B01-2A61-4A7E-89C0-110F1128DB1F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/37E6A551-D3A6-41B6-938C-C7A203803FFC/TvTestApp01.app/Frameworks/TDatabases.framework/TDatabases
  Expected in: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F88A3B01-2A61-4A7E-89C0-110F1128DB1F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/37E6A551-D3A6-41B6-938C-C7A203803FFC/TvTestApp01.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
 in /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F88A3B01-2A61-4A7E-89C0-110F1128DB1F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/37E6A551-D3A6-41B6-938C-C7A203803FFC/TvTestApp01.app/Frameworks/TDatabases.framework/TDatabases
```

In other projects that uses the same code but on macOS and iOS, those work fine.